# How can we log time spend by each module in a large pipeline in python.

Tags: python, logging, profiling, performance-testing

I have a python pipeline code which calls around 10 to 12 python classes. 
I wanted to know and log time consumed by each method in each class. 
Could anyone suggest some methods to do this in python
I'm using python inbuilt logging module for logging

Comment: Wouldn't a proper profiler be a better tool here ?

Comment: I have tried profiler. I was not able to filter the entire output provided by the profiler and I was not able to log them. It would be very helpful if you could suggest some methods where we can filter the inbuilt or library method calls and log the time and performance of modules that we have coded.

Comment: [Here](https://www.zopyx.com/andreas-jung/contents/a-python-decorator-for-measuring-the-execution-time-of-methods) there's an example of how to do that with decorators.

Comment: @Luis Muñoz. Thanks, it works. The only problem is to import the method in each py file and write it. Just one blunder question out of my curiosity is there any way we can call one method of function at the begening of the code and it times the entire code base, with minimal changes in the code???

Comment: Don't know top of my head but there should be :). Keep digging on decorators, there's a lot of magic to do there.

Comment: @Luis Muñoz  Thanksss..:) Do you know how a decorator module can be made global(like a decorator method will be written in a separate file and it can be accessed from all modules from other code). If I'm able to do that I can import it add decorater function at the starting of each module.

Comment: @Luis Muñoz got it

Comment: If you have working code post it as your own answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
import time

class myClass():
    logErrors = False
    logger = None

    def log(self, msg):
        if self.logger != None:
            self.logger.warning(msg)

    def __init__(self, log=False):
        self.logErrors = log

        if self.logErrors == True:
            self.logger = logging.getLogger("myClass")
            self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
            self.ch = logging.StreamHandler()
            self.ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            self.ch.setFormatter(formatter)
            self.logger.addHandler(self.ch)


    def method1(self):
        # log start time of method
        self.log("method1() started")

        # code
        print("foobar")
        time.sleep(1)

        # log end time of method
        self.log("method1() ended")

my = myClass(log=True)
my.method1()
```

Comment: Highly appreciated your effort. Can we make this in such a way that once we start the pipeline it logs automatically(like profiler) instead of logging in each method? I have around 50+ methods in the whole codebase It will be very painful if I need to add timing to each and every module.